# input autocomplete="off" not working in Chrome latest version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I click input type text fields the address saved in browser shows. I do't want to show it. autocomplete="off" not working in input fields within the form in chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers not always respect `autocomplete="off"` attribute.
For example when part of login form browsers will still try to save it.
If its not part of login form try `autocomplete="new-password"` to prevent autocompletion to show. (as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password))
If you use jQuery you might find this plugin useful
[jquery.disableAutoFill](https://terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill/)

Comment: bro but it's not working in chrome latest version

Comment: this should work `<input type="text" autocomplete="new-username" .... > <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" ...>`  see lengthy discussion here https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8

Comment: Have you got the solution?, I am facing issue like to disable to go back page using javascript, in previous version it's working fine but not in latest chrome version 75.0.3770.142... please do post if you got any clue