# Autocomplete="off" does not work in chrome Version 75.0.3770.142

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome 63 is ignoring autocomplete="off", and tries to suggest previous user entries.

The only solution is to assign a random string to the attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159084/input-autocomplete-off-not-working-in-chrome-latest-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the browser will continue to suggest autocomplete values even if the autocomplete attribute is disabled. The trick to not apply autocomplete is to assign an invalid value to the attribute, for example:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Since this value is not valid for the autocomplete attribute, the browser has no way of recognizing it and stops trying to autocomplete it.